# In Orbeon forms, how do I add a sidebar page navigator for multi-page forms?

Tags: forms, sidebar, orbeon

I am trying to find documentation to duplicate the following Left-Hand-Side-Bar menu found in the link below, but am having no luck: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/w9/edit/4a83b4cf2b905fbe105d7e57ddc5597b5e78c0a3

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is what is called the [wizard view](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/features/wizard-view). In essence, it transforms the top-level sections of your form into sections of a "wizard".

You can enable this in the *Form Settings* dialog (in Form Builder, click on the gear icon at the top left of the page), in the *View Options* tab.